# Customize bootstrap 4 variables using it's own variables?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am using latest Bootstrap 4 beta 2. I am trying to customize it. Mean change variables with my own.

I have my own `styles.scss` with all bootstrap imports:

```
// My variables
@import 'helpers/variables';

// Bootstrap files
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/print';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot';
// ... all others
```

Official documentation provides an [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/), how bootstrap can be customized (themed). But there is only simple example with HEX colors.

But what if I want to override variables in bootstrap `_variables.scss` and use variables from this file at the same time? For example I want to make my `$primary` black. They already have this variable inside `_variables.scss`, but I didn't found an idea how to use it. I've tried like this:

```
// source: helpers/variables
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';

$primary: $indigo;
```

But in this case blue color is used. If I remove these imports from `helpers/variables` and replace color with HEX - all works fine.

I think that there is no way to do this, because SASS will not allow this, but decided to ask community.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own variables.scss file and set it to be loaded first in your style.scss and so it will overwrite the default Bootstrap variables.

Then just copy-paste some variables from Bootstrap _variables.scss you want to change into your variables.scss and customize them.
Note that you should remove default marks in your variables.scss.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way I found. Much better do not copy them, but seems like it is not possible