# Bootstrap 4 how to overwrite scss variables that are used to define other default variables

Tags: npm, webpack, bootstrap-4

First of all I would like to mention this question: [Customize bootstrap 4 variables using it's own variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937602/customize-bootstrap-4-variables-using-its-own-variables), where it seems the same question has been asked but without fruitful answer so I thought I would ask again with a very specific example.

I basically want to overwrite some of bootstrap 4's default variables. In the example below I want to overwrite `$font-size-base`. I followed the recommended approach of the bootstrap documentation but it only seems to be partially working. Bootstrap's default variables (in `_variables.scss`) reuse other defined variables. For instance : `$input-btn-font-size: $font-size-base !default;`. When changing `$font-size-base` with the approach below however, it doesn't affect `$input-btn-font-size`.

```js
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
$font-size-base: 0.9rem;
$secondary: $gray-400;
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

On the other hand if I use the next approach where I import the variables later, then I do get the desired result where all variables that depend on `$font-size-base` get changed as well. This however is not the recommended approach and becomes clear when you want to define a variable that depends on a default variable. See `$secondary: $gray-400;`, this then throws a compile error given that `$gray-400` is unknown.

```js
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
$font-size-base: 0.9rem;
$secondary: $gray-400;
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

What is the recommended solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the override variables....

The *only* overrides that need to follow the `/variables` import are those that reference variables (ie: `$secondary: $gray-400;`).

If you just want to override a variable that doesn't reference another (ie: `$font-size-base: 2.9rem;`) that would go before the `/variables` import...

```
/* simple overrides */
$font-size-base: 2.9rem;

@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

/* var dependent overrides */
$theme-colors: (
  secondary: $gray-400
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/wpc3XKQ8TG

Note: To override a theme color such as `secondary` you must update the theme-colors map.

Comment: I've considered this option but then I thought: "What if my `$font-size-base` would reference a different variable, then it wouldn't work. So there must be something I'm missing." I guess I shouldn't have made it more complex than it needed to be.

Comment: Normally base variables aren't dependent on other vars.